# Voltmeter across two loops

Tags: electric-current, voltage

If one terminal of a voltmeter is connected to a closed loop with current and the other to an open loop, will there be a reading?

Theoretically, there is a potential difference across the terminals, but does it get detected?

Comment: By what theoretical argument is there a potential difference across the terminals?

Comment: @Alfred There is a current flowing through the closed loop, hence any point in between the loop has a non-zero potential. There is no current in other loop and potential is zero. Hence there should be a P.D.

Comment: ghosts, a physical voltmeter has a very high but finite internal resistance so, for there to be a sustained non-zero voltage reading, there must be a sustained non-zero current through.  But there is no path for a sustained current.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Thanks, I didn't think of that. You could post this comment and get some rep.